# как то можно проверить в validate request что в array каждое значение является email? Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
приходить от пользователя
 $emails = $request->validated()


class SendEmailRequest extends FormRequest
{
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'emails' => ['required', 'array']// как-то можно тут проверить что в array каждое значение является email ?
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас в массиве `$emails` находятся несколько значений, то можно сделать такую проверку:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'emails' => ['required', 'array'],
        'emails.*' => ['email']
    ];
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-arrays